# Overriding StructureMap Registry from Another Project

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have a `Unit Test` project & want to shim-in Stub implementations for the repositories within a `Unit of Work` class.  I would know how to do it using **other** IoC technologies, but  am new to StructureMap.

- How do I redefine & substitute a definition from inside my Unit Test project
- What does that look like?

I'm having trouble finding good documentation on this.

**DEFAULT CONTAINER:** 
Below is part of the business registry I hope to override.

```
public ContainerRegistry()
{
    Scan(...);

    // --------
    // UNIT OF WORK

    // This is the DEFAULT implementation
    For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(GenericRepository<>));

    For<IUnitOfWork>().Use<MeasurementContractsUnitOfWork>();
}
```

**FOR UNIT TESTS:** 
In the unit test project I want IoC to use this instead:

```
// This is the STUB Implementation
For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(GenericRepositoryStub<>));
```

**THE OBJECTIVE:** 
The objective is to simply use the container, as normal, but get the STUB shimmed-in AUTOMATICALLY.

```
var container = IoC.Initialize();
var uow = container.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure if this is the right way to do it, but this is how I accomplished my goal.  If someone gives a better answer, I will mark theirs as correct:

I created separate `IOC Initializer` & `ContainerRegistry` classes within the `Unit Test` project, like so...

**INITIALIZER CLASS:**

```
public static class IoC
{
    public static IContainer Initialize()
    {
        var container = new Container();

        // NOTE: If you have many Registries to consider, you can add them (order matters)

        // The Business Registry
        container.Configure(x => x.AddRegistry<Business.DependencyResolution.ContainerRegistry>());

        // The UnitTest Projects Registry (order matters)
        container.Configure(x => x.AddRegistry<ContainerRegistry>());

        return container;
    } 
}
```

**REGISTRY CLASS:**

```
public class ContainerRegistry : Registry
{
    public ContainerRegistry()
    {
        // The Override
        For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(GenericRepositoryIdentifiableStub<>));
    } 
}
```

[image]